# How to get user login in node?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm creating a system using `Express`, `Sequelize` and `MySQL`.

At now, I has save users in my database, and encrypting password with `bcrypt-nodejs`, but now, I'm creating the login page.

So, because all time I execute my code, `bcrypt-nodejs` is generating for me a new hash of same password, how to can I find register in my database, if password is every time different?

Or may I need use another module to encrypt password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check database for Username and fetch Password of that row .
Use compare function (bcrypt-nodejs) to compare text with that hash.

P.S : if you use salt you must save it too .